# How to remove my account ONLY from meta?

Tags: support

I am aware there is a generic question on how to remove accounts here:
[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

Yet, if I edit my profile it will display the "please delete me" message on **all** my accounts, as specified in the link itself that says:

"save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts"

So: what is the procedure to be removed **ONLY** from Meta?

Comment: You could also 'clear all stackexchange account associations' on meta, change the OpenID, then reassociate all your other accounts if you just wanted to walk away from your meta account rather than delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the left of that link there's also a regular <kbd>Save Profile</kbd> button, which saves only to this account and hence, doesn't copy the profile to all Stack Exchange network accounts:

[image]